# Using matplotlib and set pandas.series date as xtick

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, series

I have a dataframe Data read from csv file as following format:

```
0        1        2        3        4        5
0    Sat Oct 28 00:00:00 CST 2017  21.720  74112  20.4  68.7  80
1    Sat Oct 28 01:00:00 CST 2017  21.747  74204  20.7  69.3  81
2    Sat Oct 28 02:00:00 CST 2017  21.737  74170  20.6  69.1  81
...
6    Sat Oct 28 06:00:00 CST 2017  21.691  74013  20.5  68.9  76
7    Sat Oct 28 07:00:00 CST 2017  21.695  74026  20.7  69.3  73
8    Sat Oct 28 08:00:00 CST 2017  21.711  74081  20.7  69.3  73
```

As showed,the dataframe has 5 columns which label is 0-5 and several rows, `Data[0]` represent the first column `Sat Oct 28 01:00:00 CST 2017`, `Data[1]` represent `21.720` and `Data[2]` represent `74112` .I want to set `Data[0]` as **xticks** and `Data[2]` as **yticks** using matplotlib, How can this be done?  
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To set data[0] as the xticks, use

```
plt.xticks(data['0'])
```

and for y:

```
plt.yticks(data['1'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: :) Np Hope it helped!

Comment: When I using plt.xticks(data[0]), this error showed: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'Is it because data[0]'s type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>?

Comment: I believe this would be because you have times as data[0]. Try removing plt.xticks() for now and see if the plot works with just plt.yticks() specified. By the way, it is not clear in your question which column is data[0] and which is data[2], please try to edit your question so it is more clear.

Comment: The first column is "Sat Oct 28 00:00:00 CST 2017",I think it is a str type.Should I convert the first column to datetime?

Comment: Yes that should help, Matplotlib does not recognize strings as ticks.

Comment: What plot are you trying to make? Matplotlib has a plt.plot_dates() function that allows you to plot datetime values as well.

Comment: I tried plt.plot_datas(data[0],data[1],'r') function,the data[0] is been auto recognized as dates and xticks are set on figure.But the y values become not a continuous line,it is separate on several places.